# How to center triangle in rectangle?

Tags: triangles, interpolation, angle, floating-point

I have the green rectangle (size/shape can vary) centered in the chart (black master rectangle).

I want know how to draw two lines (or a triangle, shown in my picture in red) through the green rectangle in such way that the lines are passing exactly through the corners of the green rectangle.

I know x1,y1  x2,y2.  I need to know how to compute x?,y?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to calculate the $x$ and $y$ coordinates based on? Do you want a formula based on the coordinates of the triangles, the coordinates of the rectangle and so on?

Comment: @TobyMak-
 
The triangles are not there. I must draw them. So, based on the coordinates of the (green) rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by other answer, for the upper point, what you need to do is

- construct a line $\ell_1$ passing through $p_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ and $p_1 = (x_1,y_1)$,
- construct a line $\ell_2$ passing through $p_m = (x_{max},y_0)$ and $p_2 = (x_2,y_2)$.
- find the intersection $p = (x,y)$ of lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$.

The answer is a horrible mess:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{(x_1-x_0)(x_{max} y_2-x_2y_0)-(x_2-x_{max})(x_0y_1-x_1y_0)}{(x_2-x_{max})(y_0-y_1)-(x_1-x_0)(y_0-y_2)}\\
y &= \frac{(x_0y_1-x_1y_0)(y_0-y_2)-(y_0-y_1)(x_{max} y_2-x_2y_0)}{(x_2-x_{max})(y_0-y_1)-(x_1-x_0)(y_0-y_2)}
\end{align}
$$

If you know [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and has access to a library which knows how to compute cross product, there is a simpler way to describe and calculate $p$.

First, some background mathematics.

For any point $p = (u,v)$, we can represent it by triplets
of the from $(ut, vt, t)$ where $t \ne 0$. 
For any line $\ell : ax + by + c = 0$, we can represent it by triplets
of the form $(as, bs, cs)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ where $s \ne 0$.
These are called [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) for point $p$ and line $\ell$.
In particular, we will use $\vec{p} = (u,v,1)$ and $\vec{\ell} = (a,b,c)$ to
denote one particular set of homogeneous coordinates for $p$ and $\ell$.

In terms of homogeneous coordinates, some geometric relations among points and lines have nice algebraic correspondences. For example,

- point $p$ lies on line $\ell$ is equivalent to $\;\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\ell} = 0$.
- line $\ell$ passes through point $p_1$ and $p_2$ is equivalent to $\;\vec{\ell} \propto \vec{p}_1 \times \vec{p}_2$.
- lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ intersect at point $p$ is equivalent to $\;\vec{p} \propto \vec{\ell}_1 \times \vec{\ell}_2$.

Apply this to the problem of determining lines $\ell_1, \ell_2$ and hence 
point $p$ from points $p_0 = (x_0,y_0), p_m = (x_{max},y_0), p_1 = (x_1,y_1)$,
and $p_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, we obtain

- $\vec{\ell}_1 \propto \vec{p}_0 \times \vec{p}_1$,
- $\vec{\ell}_2 \propto \vec{p}_m \times \vec{p}_2$,
- $\vec{p} \propto \vec{\ell}_1 \times \vec{\ell}_2
  \propto (\vec{p}_0 \times \vec{p}_1 ) \times ( \vec{p}_m \times \vec{p}_2)$.

This means once we have computed the components of following cross product,
$$(u_x, u_y, u_z) \stackrel{def}{=} (\vec{p}_0 \times \vec{p}_1 ) \times ( \vec{p}_m \times \vec{p}_2)$$
the coordinates for the desired intersection $p$ is given by
$\displaystyle\;(x,y) = \left(\frac{u_x}{u_z},\frac{u_y}{u_z}\right)$.

Comment: wow. somebody that knows mathematics (and also knows how to write a StackExchange answer). thanks and Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Derive a formula for the two lines that connect the same corner of both boxes, then calculate the intersection of the two lines.

Comment: You mean what is the formula for a line, given two points on the line? Surely you can Google "Wikipedia line" and learn this (and the method to determine where two lines intersect) on your own.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#On_the_Cartesian_plane is a good place to start.

Comment: now, take a look below and see what an ANSWER means. no wonder that buy has 73K points!

Comment: @BorlImpriceGoGearEmbaIdera I don't think it's more useful to hand the asker an explicit formula when what they actually need is a methodology for finding the answer. This question is one the asker should be able to figure out on their own, and it's more valuable for them to determine the answer by putting effort into it. The goal here should be to lead the asker to a place where they don't need to ask every time they need a specific solution. As for my rating, I rarely ask and answer on SE, even though I find it very useful. Naturally, I agree the answerer has earned their rating.

Comment: you should include the "search google" in your answer :) :)